The scaling effect on the Besov norm
The Besov spaces can be defined using the dyadic decomposition.  For this purpose,  let $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ be such
$ {\rm supp}(\varphi) \subseteq \left\{x; \,  \frac 12<  |x| < 2\right\}$ and denote
$$\varphi_j(x) = \varphi\left(2^{-j}x\right)\quad\text{for} \quad j\in \mathbb N^\ast\quad \text{and}\quad \varphi_0 = 1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty \varphi_j.$$
For any $\sigma\in \mathbb R$ and $0< p, q \leq \infty,$ define the  Besov space
$$B_{pq}^\sigma:=  \left\{ v \in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n);\,\,  \|v\|_{B_{pq}^\sigma} := \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{j\sigma q} \left\| \mathfrak{F}^{-1} (\varphi_j \hat v)\right\|_p^q  \right)^{\frac 1q} <\infty \right\},$$
where $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n)$ denotes the space of tempered distributions and $\mathfrak{F}^{-1}$ is the  inverse Fourier transform.
Let now $v\in B_{pq}^\sigma$ and $a> 0.$ Define $u(x) := v(a x).$ I wonder what the relationship between $\|v\|_{B_{pq}^\sigma}$ and $\|u\|_{B_{pq}^\sigma}$ is!
It is natural to start with the following:
$$\hat u(\xi) = a^{-n} \hat v\left( a^{-1} \xi\right).$$
Furthermore, we write $$\mathfrak{F}^{-1} [\varphi_j \hat u](x)= a^{-n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot x} \varphi_j (\xi) \hat v\left( a^{-1} \xi\right) d \xi = \int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{2\pi i  a \xi \cdot x} \varphi_j (a \xi) \hat v(\xi)\, d \xi
=\mathfrak{F}^{-1} [\varphi_j (a\cdot) \hat u]( ax).$$
A change of variable  $a x \to x$ inside the $L^p$ norm gives  a factor $ a^{-n/p}.$
Hence, combining all above together we can write
$$\|u\|_{B_{pq}^\sigma} = a^{-n/p} \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{j\sigma q} \left\| \mathfrak{F}^{-1} (\varphi_j (a\cdot) \hat v)\right\|_p^q  \right)^{\frac 1q},$$
where the r.h.s term is not written in terms of the Besov norm of $v.$ The scaling on $\varphi$ seems to affect the factor $2^{\sigma jq}$ in the sum, but I have no idea how.
Thank you for any contribution.

I think it is easier to use the integral representation of Besov norms with finite differences, for example for $s\in(0,1)$, $|v|{B^s{p,q}} \simeq | |v(x+z)-v(x)|{L^p_x}/|z|^{s+n/q}|{L^q_z}$. This gives $|v(ax)|{B^s{p,q}} = a^{s-n/p} |v|{B^s{p,q}} $

There should be then a norm equivalence !  Could this equality be extended for any $s\geq 0$ ?

Yes, there are analogous formulas for higher $s$ with higher order differences. See e.g. Triebel's books on Functional spaces.

This paper might be a good starting point: http://www.mat.ucm.es/serv/revmat/vol22-1/vol22-1g.pdf It seems to indicate that things get quite subtle for $s$ small (or even negative).

@PhoemueX seems to be very special case $a = 2^k$ !

@LL3.14 I don't have access to this book. I tried to find it in the free pages in the google link
https://books.google.de/books?id=Nf3LPOf0Q3kC&pg=PA85&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false

For every $a\geq 2$, you can choose k such that $2^k \leq a \leq 2^{k+1}$. I would expect (without formal proof at the moment) that then the norms of dilation by a and by $2^k$ behave similarly.
